# Angular | Set form control element that implements ControlValueAccessor as disabled from within

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, controlvalueaccessor

I have a component that implements `ControlValueAccessor`.
At first the form control element is disabled.

**app.component.html**

```
<ng-container [formGroup]="form">
  <custom-input formControlName="input"></custom-input>
</ng-container>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
form = this.fb.group({
  input: [{ value: 'MyValue', disabled: true }],
});
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to change it's state from disable to enable from inside the `custom-input` component.

Here is a sample app where the scenario is replicated [StackBlitz App](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-dpdofg?file=src/app/app.component.html).

Comment: Hey, when working with reactive forms you can manage all the logic of your inputs with the reference of the formGroup.
I'm sharing your fixed   [stackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bmbmij?file=src/app/custom-input.component.ts) .

what I did is inject the component that holds the form group and get a reference to the input in the form group and then I used the enable() and disable method available in each form control

Comment: I see! Thank you. Is this the recommended way of doing it?

Comment: The way I would do it is to inject the form via @Input to custom-input